# Reference VSTO Excel ListObject's columns by header name instead of column index

Tags: excel, vsto

Actually I can easily read the content of a ListObject in VSTO using the following code.

In this example I'm reading all the products from a given sheet. The data is edited using a Excel Table, which tranlates to an ListObject inside VSTO. I'm using VS2010 with .NET 4.0 and also, Excel 2010.

```
private IEnumerable<Produto> ReadFromWorksheet()
{
    var produtosLidos = new List<Produto>();


    try
    {
        foreach (Excel.ListRow row in Globals.Sheet1.tblProdutos.ListRows)
        {

            var id = RangeUtils.ToInt(row.Range[1, 1]) ?? -1;
            var codigo = RangeUtils.ToString(row.Range[1, 2]);
            var nome = RangeUtils.ToString(row.Range[1, 3]);
            var qtdDisp = RangeUtils.ToDecimal(row.Range[1, 4]);
            var unidMed = RangeUtils.ToString(row.Range[1, 5]);
            var valor = RangeUtils.ToDecimal(row.Range[1, 6]);


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(codigo) ||nome == null || qtdDisp == null || unidMed == null || valor == null)
                throw new ApplicationException("Os campos Nome, Qtd. Disponível, Unid. de Medida e Valor são obrigatórios.");


            var p = new Produto();
            p.Id = id;
            p.CodigoProduto = codigo;
            p.Nome = nome;
            p.QtdDisponivel = qtdDisp;
            p.UnidadeMedida = unidMed;
            p.Valor = valor;
            p.DataUltimaAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
            p.Acao = RangeUtils.ToString(row.Range[1, 8]);
            p.Ativo = true;

            produtosLidos.Add(p);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
    return produtosLidos;
}
```

But sometimes the user wants do add another row or even change the column order of the table. So I would like to know if there's a better way to reference each row by the column name instead of the column index.

An acceptable solution for this would be something like this:

```
var myValue = row.Range[1, "My Value"];
```

Thanks in advance for any advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar issue. Here is what I did to get to the header names:

```
private void listSPRData_BeforeDoubleClick(Range Target, ref bool Cancel)
{
    foreach (Range c in Target.ListObject.HeaderRowRange.Cells)
    {
        // Do something...
        // "c.Value" contains the name of your header.
        // When you find your column, you can break to avoid unnecessary looping.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to develop a custom solution to overcome this kind of situation. Basically, where loading VSTO, the trick is to map all columns and their indexes on a dictionary and store this mapping in a class field.  public void ReadColumnPositions()
        {
            cols = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            object[,] columnData = _tbl.HeaderRowRange.Value;
            
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnData.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                cols.Add(columnData[1, i].ToString(), i);
            }   
        }

Answer (score 1):

```
Sheet1.ListObjects("dataTable").DataBodyRange(2, "b").Value
```

Assuming your table is named dataTable which has 3 columns (a,b,c) and 2 rows.
Note: I am using VBA. I assume your could should work when using `DataBodyRange`.

```
var myValue = Sheet1.ListObjects("dataTable").DataBodyRange[1, "myColumnHeader"];
```

Comment: Hello @shahkalpesh, I tried this technique and it didn't work. It seems that VSTO doesn't accept this way of accessing columns. The exception is: Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)). I tried with the following code: for (int i = 1; i <= Globals.Sheet1.tblProdutos.ListRows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var value = _tbl.DataBodyRange[1, "Valor Previsto"];
                    Debug.WriteLine(value);
                }

Comment: @MárioMeyrelles: Can you try & see if the above VBA code works in your case with the table name, sheet name, column name modified as per your settings?

Comment: Hi again @shahkalpesh, I tried this approach inside VBA and it didn't work. 
Sub Button1_Click()

'Works fine
Debug.Print Sheet6.ListObjects("tblSaidas").DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value

'Does not work
Debug.Print Sheet6.ListObjects("tblSaidas").DataBodyRange(1, "Valor Previsto").Value

End Sub

Comment: It seems that the only possible way to reference a ListObject' column is using it's index. Another way is using a Range syntax like "tblSaida[Valor Previsto]". Thanks in advance anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about Sheet1.ListObjects("dataTable").ListColumns["ColumnName"].Range[rowOfInterest]?

Comment: Compiler error:  "non-invocable member 'sheet1.ListObjects' cannot be used like a method.

Answer (score 0):

Since ListObject doesn't provide that functionality, alternatively you could use Range.Find..

```
Range cellFind = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What: "Column your looking for", After: Type.Missing, LookIn: Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, LookAt: Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, SearchOrder: Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, SearchDirection: Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: false);

if (cellFind != null)
{
   int columnIndex = cellFind.Column;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* access ListObject columns directly by column name. @shahkalpesh and @gap are close, but the indexer idiom (VBA, not c#) on the ListObjects is missmatched. The example below builds a simple table, references the second column by its name, "ColName2", and modifies the first data cell in the second column;

```
object[,] Data = new object[,] {{  "ColName1", "ColName2"}, {  11, 12 }, {21, 22 }};
Excel.Range tblRange = Globals.SParameters.Range["B20:C22"];
tblRange.Value = Data;

Globals.SParameters.Controls.AddListObject(tblRange, "tblProdutos");
Globals.SParameters.ListObjects["tblProdutos"].ListColumns["ColName2"].DataBodyRange[1] = 55;
```

Note that you can use 'DataBodyRange' or 'Range'; 'DataBodyRange' excludes the column header, which is usually appropriate.